# Will shorthand declaration of variable, involving already defined one, allocate new memory?

Tags: go

I have a function that returns to values `user` and `err` . When I call it in scope I already have variable `user`, but don’t have variable `err` , so compiler/linter tells me to use `:=` operator syntax (I know I can declare `err` somewhere before this call with `var` declaration), making it look like this:

```golang
user := User{"Name"}
...
user, err := functionThatReturnsTwoValues()
if err != nil {
...
```

**Question: In this specific case, in the line `user, err := functionThatReturnsTwoValues` , will user variable be redeclared?**

**P.S.** I also understand that from actual results, it doesn't matter for me, as in the end, I will have variable with correct data after function call in any case. Also the fact, that variable will be defined in the stack in our case, means there will be no garbage collection involved to clean it up, even if there were 2 `User` structs initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think *user* variable is not re-declared, but of course its value is overridden. I've tested via checking the variable's pointer addresses as below. As you may see the pointers which are used for capturing variable addresses stays same.

https://play.golang.org/p/bj3QwSgCCiG

Snipped:

```
func main() {
    user := User{"Name"}
    up1 := &user

    user, err := functionThatReturnsTwoValues()
    up2 := &user

    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("User: %v \n", user)
        fmt.Printf("Pointer check :  up1 ?=  up2 --> %t [up1=%p, up2=%p]\n", up1 == up2, up1, up2)
        fmt.Printf("Value check   : *up1 ?= *up2 --> %t \n", *up1 == *up2)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
User: {Name2}  
Pointer check :  up1 ?=  up2 --> true [up1=0x40c138, up2=0x40c138]
Value check   : *up1 ?= *up2 --> true
```

Comment: This is guaranteed by [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec), and as your example shows, it matters if you've captured the address of the originally-declared variable, since you now access the same object by name (`user`) and by pointer (`*up1`).

Answer (score 2):

The user variable will be used to store the result of the function, see below an example

https://play.golang.org/p/eHHycX4p16j

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the variable is redeclared and its value is overridden. But it must still have the same type declaration. The redeclaration essentially drops down to an assignment and the same stack memory is used.

This is explicitly allowed by the spec to make cases such as defining err neater:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.
>   - https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

For example:

```
var user User
user, err := fetchUser() // OK: user redeclared but new err variable declared
user, err := fetchUser() // Bad: user and err variable redeclared, but no new variables declared
user, err = fetchUser() // OK: No declarations, only assignments
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, the variable user will be redeclared. From the Go Language Specification:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

See the specification of [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, shorthand declaration will redefine it.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        i := 1
        i, x := giveMeTwos()
        fmt.Println(i, x)
}

func giveMeTwos() (int, int) {
        return 2, 2
}
```